# HLookup from one spreadsheet to Another

Tags: vba, excel

Please help HLookup from one workbook to another for n number of iteration

```
    Windows(Files).Activate
    Sheets("Total").Select
    Set myrange = Sheets("Total").Range("1:5")
    Windows(ThisFileName).Activate
    Sheets("Acc").Select
    Range("B" & n + 2, "V" & n + 2).Select     
    ActiveRange("B" & n + 2, "V" & n + 2).Formula = HLookup(Acc.Range("B" & n + 1, "V" & n + 1), myrange, 2, False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a string representing the worksheet formula.

```
Set myrange = workSheets("Total").Range("1:5")

with workSheets("Acc").Range("B" & n + 2, "V" & n + 2)
    .Formula = "=hlookup(" & .address & ", " & myrange.address(external:=true) & ", 2, False)"
end with
```